# Can I reduce the consumption of a Peltier cell by lowing down its voltage?

Tags: cooling, voltage

I have recently bought a [Peltier cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_cooling): a [small board](http://m.banggood.com/TEC1-12715-12V-Heatsink-Thermoelectric-Cooler-Peltier-Plate-Module-p-909864.html?utm_campaign=PSALE-333099-7054694253-OPENPID909864&utm_content=ccp&utm_medium=ADshare&utm_source=sem) that cools any device, like a CPU or a GPU.

[image: Peltier Cell]

I have tested it and it works fine, but its power consumption is too high, due to its intake of 12 Volts 15 Amperes: more than 100 Watts.

I would like to be able to control/manage the “strength” of my Peltier's cell. Is that possible? Maybe the cell would be damaged?

Many motherboards can slow down the speed of computer fans (12 Volts operational voltage, too) by reducing the voltage sent to the fan jack (10, 8 or even less Volts).

Assuming I could develop a method to control the DC Voltage intake to the Peltier's cell, would it keep working at a lower consumption?

Of course, I assume that cooling will not be so effective at, say, 8 Volts, than it would be at 12 Volts, but it does not bother me as long as it keeps cooling.